# AWS Cloudfront and S3 redirects lose custom domain name

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a S3 static website set up using CloudFront for HTTPS. I'm trying to add redirect rules, but I can't get it all to work together.

I have a Cloudfront distribution for www.mysite.com pointing at mysite.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com. This works great. It serves the default index page and custom error page. However, I now want to move page1 to page2. I tried setting up a redirect rule:

```
<RoutingRule>
  <Condition>
    <KeyPrefixEquals>page1</KeyPrefixEquals>
  </Condition>
  <Redirect>
    <ReplaceKeyWith>page2</ReplaceKeyWith>
  </Redirect>
</RoutingRule>
```

The redirect is triggered; however, it redirects away from mysite.com/page1 -> mysite.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/page2!

Note: I can't use 301 redirect pages because some of the actual redirects are hash-related.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remember we had the following,

```
<RoutingRule>
  <Condition>
    <KeyPrefixEquals>page1</KeyPrefixEquals>
  </Condition>
  <Redirect>
    <HostName>www.mysite.com</HostName>
    <ReplaceKeyWith>page2</ReplaceKeyWith>
  </Redirect>
</RoutingRule>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It works for me as well, but I had to wait something like 20 minutes before changes were applied.